# Como sobreescribir constante en c en el programa

Tags: c, float

Estoy realizando un programa en C en el que en el main se declara una variable tipo `float`. Más tarde, el usuario, desde un `switch case`, debe cambiarla y que esa pase a ser la constante oficial. ¿Como puedo hacer esto? (Debe ser con void)

```
int operacion;

int main ()
{ 
    float paso;    
    paso = 0.65;

    scanf ("%d", &operacion);

    switch (operacion){
    case 1:
        printf("El valor actual del paso es de %f \n",paso);
        printf("Introduzca el nuevo valor para la medición del paso\n");
        scanf("%f",&paso);
```

Comment: Escribe tu código para que sea mas fácil comprender la pregunta.

Comment: Amigo, primero quiero que aclares algo. "Constante (informática)
En programación, una constante es un valor que no puede ser alterado/modificado durante la ejecución de un programa, únicamente puede ser leído." Con eso explicado puede que tu pregunta este mal formulada. Quizás lo quieras es tener una variable global la cual debería estar inicializada con el valor que tu le quieras y luego que la variable "paso" le remplace el valor ingresado por el usuario.

Comment: Bueno no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero puede esto te ayude a comprender un poco el problema que tienes, en general una constante no se supone que pueda cambiar de valor, con lo que estas haciendo ya estas sobre escribiendo el valor que tiene la variable paso, por lo que si fuera del switch imprimes dicha variable podrás ver su nuevo valor.

Comment: Estás confundiendo el concepto ["constante" en sentido matemático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constante_%28matemáticas%29), con el concepto de ["constante" en el contexto de programación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constante_(informática)).

Answer (score 1):

Espero sea de ayuda, una constante no se puede cambiar, una variable si. Hay dos maneras de definir constantes. A traves de cabecera #define paso 0.65 o a través de la definción de la función. const int paso = 0.65; Las constantes son eso, constantes siempre y son de solo lectura.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int operacion, salida;
  float paso = 0.65;
  printf("El valor actual de paso es de %f \n", paso);
  printf("¿Que desea hacer?\n");
  printf("A) Conservar el valor de paso y seguir\n");
  printf("B) Cambiar el valor de paso.\n");
  printf("Inserte una opción aqui: ");
  scanf("%s", &operacion);
  operacion = toupper(operacion);

  switch(operacion){
    case 'A':
      printf("El valor de paso es de: %.2f", paso);
      break;
    case 'B':
      printf("Inserte el nuevo valor de paso: ");
      scanf("%f", &paso);
      printf("El valor de paso es de: %.2f", paso);
      break;
    default:
      printf("El valor no es una opción de menú.\n");

  }
  puts("\n Pulsa cualquier tecla para continuar...");
  salida = getchar();
}
```